# Determine if Nested Key Exists in JSON Response - VBA

Tags: arrays, json, excel, vba

I'm having trouble parseing a JSON response into Excel.  The issue is due to null value in one of the nested arrays.  I have no problem reading the value into the file when it exists, but I am having difficulty putting a check to verify that it does exist.

I can access the id  value of field2, but if field2 comes back as null, it throws an error. I've tried a few different ways to check if id of field2 exists, with no success

```
         For Each Value In JsonObject("value")
        ws.Cells(rowindex, 21) = Value("value1")("id")
        For Each Item In Value("field1")
            If field1.Exists("field2")("id") Then
            'If field1.("field2").Exists("id") Then
                ws.Cells(rowindex, 22) = field1("field2")("id")
            End If
            ws.Cells(rowindex, 25) = field1("config")("id")
        Next
        rowindex = rowindex + 1
 Next
```

and the JSON file

```
    {
 "value": [
  {
   "value1": {
    "id": "123",
   },
   "field1": [
    {
     "config": {
      "id": "131",
     },
     "field2": {
      "id": "a594c0fc-6ddb-64da-b0e8-c544f2bbbe3e",
     }
    },{
     "config": {
      "id": "320",
     },
     "field2": {
      "id": "a594c0fc-6ddb-64da-b0e8-c544f2bbbe3e",
     }
    }]
  },{
   "value1": {
    "id": "456",
   },
   "field1": [
    {
     "config": {
      "id": "131",
     },
     "field2": null
    },{
     "config": {
      "id": "320",
     },
     "field2": null
    }]
  }],
 "count": 2
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this (untested):

```
For Each Item In Value("field1")
    If item = "field2" Then
       If Not IsNull(item("field2")("id")) Then
          '....
       End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: This got me on the right track.  I only needed one If Statemment - If Not IsNull(field1("tester")) Then.